# "Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Data"

Tags: c#, mysql, mono

Well, I'm writing my very first program in C#. I do it on my Ubuntu machine, using mono. What I want to implement - is to connect to MySQL. So, I downloaded a library from the Oracle site and installed it like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mono-gac
$ sudo gacutil -i MySql.Data.dll
```

In my program I have such lines of code:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

class db {
     ....
     public void Connect(){
          MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(
"server=localhost;userid=root;password=root; database=my_db; pooling=false;");
     }

}
```

And I compile this program like so:

```
$ mcs db.cs -r:MySql.Data.dll
```

but as a result, I get this error message:

> Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Data ...

I should add, that if I just comment `Connect()` method and leave all the rest code unchanged, then the program is compiled ok. So, I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear. In order to be able to use the `MySqlConnection` type, you need a reference to `System.Data`, which resides in System.Data.dll.

So `... -r:System.Data.dll`.